# Swift: How to copy from Data to OpaquePointer?

Tags: c, swift

I have a Swift function called from C. The function is defined in C like so:

```
    int (*load_session_func)(
        signal_buffer **record,
        const signal_protocol_address *address,
        void *user_data);
```

The Swift equivalent is this:

```
    public var load_session_func: (@convention(c)
        record: (UnsafeMutablePointer<OpaquePointer?>?,
        address: UnsafePointer<signal_protocol_address>?,
        userData: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
     -> Int32)!
```

So I need to implement load_session_func() in Swift, and put some Data bytes into the **record** parameter. How does one put the bytes from Data into OpaquePointer? I can't use withUnsafeBytes because the C code will use the bytes after my function returns.

Comment: Can C code modify the record bytes?  Is your Swift code going to use the bytes modified by C code?  Is it a problem to keep 2 or more copies of the bytes?  Does `Data` absolutely have to be the data type for storing the bytes in Swift?  Just trying to get an idea of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The Swift code seems to act as a storage for the C code to call to store and load. The API is defined [here](https://github.com/WhisperSystems/libsignal-protocol-c/blob/master/src/signal_protocol.h)